# Find a function that is positive definite, Hermitian, homogeneous, but not additive.

Tags: functional-analysis

Can anyone give an example of a function $s:E$x$E->K$ that mimics all inner product properties except additivity? ($K$ is Real or Complex and $E$ is a linear space)
It has to satisfy: positive-definiteness ($s(x,x)>=0$ and $s(x,x)=0=>x=0$), conjugate symmetry $s(y,x)=conjugate(s(x,y)$), homogeneity $s(ax,y)=a*s(x,y)$, but it can't satisfy additivity $s(x+y,z)=s(x,z)+s(y,z)$. 
Functions like $x^2+y^2$ won't do, because $(a*x)^2+y^2=a^2*x^2+y^2\neq a*(x^2+y^2)$ so $s(ax,y)\neq a*s(x,y)$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please improve your question by including more context: what is the inner product you are referring to (just the standard $L_2$-one?). Also, please make it clearer what your own thoughts are.

Comment: I need to find a function that satisfies positive-definiteness (s(x,x)>=0 and s(x,x)=0=>x=0), conjugate symmetry s(y,x)=conjugate(s(x,y)), homogeneity s(ax,y)=a*s(x,y), but is not additive s(x+y,z)=s(x,z)+s(y,z). Where s:ExE->K (K is Real or Complex), and E is a linear space

Comment: I see: you are looking for a function that mimics all the properties of an inner product with the exception of additivity. Could you possibly make this clearer in your question?

Answer (score 0):

On $\mathbb R^2$ you can work with polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$. Then define the product as
$$
\langle (r_1,\phi_1), (r_2,\phi_2) \rangle: = r_1r_2.
$$
Then $\langle x,x\rangle \ge 0$, $\langle x,x\rangle=0$ if and only if $x=0$. The product is homogeneous, as multiplication does only affect the radial coordinate.

Comment: So, how would I disprove the additivity with the given function:Would't it just be ((r1,ф1)+(r2,ф2),(r3,ф3))=(r1+r2)*r3=r1*r3+r2*r3=((r1,ф1),(r3,ф3))+((r2,ф2),(r3,ф3)) which would just prove the additivity?

Comment: No. check addition in polar coordinates: $(r_1,\phi_1)+(r_2,\phi_2)\ne (r_1+r_2,\phi_1+\phi_2)$.

Comment: Is it not true that the sum of vectors $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ in Cartesian coordinates that is $(3,3)$ is the sum of vectors $(sqrt(2),Pi/4)+(sqrt(8),Pi/4)$ which is $(3*sqrt(2),Pi/2)$, meaning that $(sqrt(2)+sqrt(8),Pi/4+Pi/4)=>(r1+r2,φ1+φ2)=(r1,φ1)+(r2,φ2)$

Comment: No, it is not. $(3,3)$ in Cartesian coordinates is $(3\sqrt 2,\pi/4)$ in polar coordinates (and not $(3\sqrt 2,\pi/2)$)!

Comment: Wouldn't the constant be affected when you take
 $a*r1=sqrt((a*r1*cosφ1)^2+(a*r1*sinφ1)^2)=sqrt(a^2)*r1=a*r1$ giving an a that is nonnegative (just like $|a|=sqrt(a^2)=a>0$), that would fail to satisfy the property 
$s(ax,y)=a*s(x,y)$ when a<0